# Why can't I transform the match token in PowerShell's replace operator?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-core

Was trying to simplify some PowerShell string replacement code, and came across something I can't quite explain. To be clear, I know how to find a substring and replace it/transform it with another value. **What I'm asking for here is an explanation of this behavior and why it doesn't work this way.**

With a regular string, whether it's a variable or hard-coded, I can modify the string how I see fit after it has been rendered. For example:

```
($greeting = 'HELLO'.ToLower()) # ===> hello
```

This produces the expected output by returning a lowercase copy of the string. However, I tried  this using the `-replace` operator and was met with an interesting result:

```
$greeting -replace '\w+', '$0'.ToUpper() # ===> hello
```

I was expecting the matched pattern in the string to be replaced with an uppercase copy of the match, but this isn't happening. I tried a few other increasingly ugly methods to see if there was some way to get this to work but to no avail:

```
$greeting -replace '\w+', ('$0').ToUpper() # ===> hello
$greeting -replace '\w+', "$(('$0').ToUpper())" # ===> hello
$greeting -replace '\w+', "`$0".ToUpper() # === hello
$greeting -replace '\w+', '`$0'.ToString().ToUpper() # ===> hello
$greeting -replace '\w+', (('$0').ToString()).ToUpper() # ===> hello
```

I also tried `-creplace` in place of `-replace` for a few of these but that also didn't have any effect. Why am I unable to transform the result of a match when using PowerShell's `-replace` operator?

I tested this with both PowerShell 5.1 and 7 so this behavior extends between MS PowerShell and PowerShell Core.

Comment: Or `'hello' | % toupper`

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the questions linked above. I'm asking about the behavior here and why it behaves this way, not asking how to transform text found with a regular expression.

Comment: Sometimes the timing of the replace 2nd arg isn't ideal.  But you need ps 7 to use the scriptblock version.  [regex]::replace() is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToUpper()` is executed *before* the resulting upper-case string is passed to `-replace` as the substitute argument - and the upper-case version of `$0` is just `$0`, so no different from omitting `.ToUpper()` entirely.

If you want `ToUpper()` called as part of the substitution routine you have to [pass a scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#scriptblock-substitutions) as the substitute argument:

```bsh
$greeting -replace '\w+', {$_.Value.ToUpper()}
```

This only works in PowerShell 6.2 and up, in Windows PowerShell you have to call `[regex]::Replace()` directly:

```
[regex]::Replace($greeting, '\w+', {param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper()})
```

Comment: That behavior actually seems really obvious now. I should have been tipped off when using `'$0'` that no replacement could be happening yet, because of the single quotes.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Hindsight is always 20/20 ^_^